# BackEndless.Com - Asynchronous Login in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, backendless

I am using backendless.com as my backend for my application. I need to log my user in within a fragment. I keep getting a syntax error stating that the Asynchronous login method provided by backendless.com is not recognized. It works perfectly fine within an Activity. Does anyone know how to get it to work within a Fragment? Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Here is the code for my Fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private Button registerButton, resetButton, loginButton;
EditText userName, password;
private boolean isPopUpOpen;
BackendlessUser userOne = new BackendlessUser();
private static final String PREFS_LOGGED_IN = "AreYouLoggedInFile";

public OnClickedListener listener;
public LogInInterface loggedInListener;

static interface OnClickedListener{
    public void buttonClicked(View v);
}

static interface LogInInterface{
    public void userLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (OnClickedListener)activity;
    this.loggedInListener = (LogInInterface)activity;
}

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    isPopUpOpen = false;
    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isDialogOpen")){
            resetPopUpWindow();
        }
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    registerButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    resetButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_login_password);
    userName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_login_username);

    loginButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_login_loginButton);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.register_button:{
            listener.buttonClicked(v);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.reset_button:{
            isPopUpOpen = true;
            resetPopUpWindow();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.fragment_login_loginButton:{
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
            progressDialog.show();//FOLLOWING METHOD NOT WORKING...



            Backendless.UserService.login("email", password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser user) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_LOGGED_IN, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                    editor.commit();

                }

                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: you are having a syntax error. What parameters take the login mathod from Backendless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `login()` method for `Backendless` expects a `String` as the second parameter. You're passing it an `EditText`. You have to extract the value out of the `EditText`. Do `password.getText().toString()` as your second parameter to the `login()` method.

And, its a good practice to check for empty value in the EditText before you actually send the value. So make sure to do those checks.

Comment: Wow, that was dumb. Thank you. I'll accept in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

As this [website](https://backendless.com/documentation/users/android/users_login.htm) mentions the login method syntax is like this:

```
public void Backendless.UserService.login( String login, 
                                          String password, 
                                          AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser> callback );

public void Backendless.UserService.login( String login, 
                                          String password, 
                                          boolean stayLoggedIn, 
                                          AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser> callback );
```

and you are passing an `EditText` instead of a `String`. So replace this:

```
Backendless.UserService.login("email", password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser user) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_LOGGED_IN, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                    editor.commit();

                }

                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

with this:

```
Backendless.UserService.login("email", password.getText().toString(), new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser user) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_LOGGED_IN, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                    editor.commit();

                }

                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps!!!